# Solving multiple matrix equations

Tags: matrices

I am looking to method to solve for x where x is non-negative.
Satisfying all the equations below:

> **A**x = c, **B**x = d, **E**x = f, ...

**A,B,E,..** are 12 by 12 matrices, for example:
$$\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0.1 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
        0 & 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.01 & \cdots & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0.01 & \cdots & 0\\
        \end{matrix}
\right] $$

c,d,f,.. are the given outcome 12 by 1 vector, for example:
$$\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1244\\
        9030\\
        \vdots\\
        534\\
        \end{matrix}
\right] $$

I am able to solve the equations individually but, how should I solve for *x* simultaneously?

Comment: What's the rank of your matrices? It could be that your system is overdetermined / incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the equations to get one system of equations:

$\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\\
E\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}  \vec{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c\\
d\\
f\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$

Depending on the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\\
E\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$, you may have one,many or no solutions. Things like the Moore-penrose pseudinverse may be useful in some cases (minimum norm least squares slution). This may lead to solutions which are both positive and negative.

However, one can add a non-negativity constraint to $\vec{x}$ and then have a linear/quadratic program.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but in this manner the x would be need to be a repeated x,x,x,... and there is no guarantee that the solution would cause it to repeat.

Comment: No it wouldn't. If you repeated x, the dimensions wouldn't match up.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for non-negative solutions, I would recommend looking at linear programming solvers for a task like this. Just plug in a dummy objective.